# Eclipse will not run project unless I close and reopen it

Tags: eclipse

My issue happens anytime I make a change to my code, even something as simple as inserting/removing a breakpoint. After making a change, I need to then close my java project, reopen it, and clean it. Only then can I run my project or class without it running the PREVIOUS version of the file(s) I changed. Saving it does nothing. Refreshing it does nothing.

Why did eclipse decide to start trolling me all of a sudden? How can I fix this?

Comment: It happened to me too. My solution: IntelliJ.

Comment: Just to clarify: When I click the "Run" button in Eclipse, it runs an older version of my code (the version before anything I edited). So I have to run two times (the second one runs accordnadly).

Comment: Is auto build active?

Comment: Netbeans is pretty good these days...

Comment: Please try to find relevant error in error log https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_Where_can_I_find_that_elusive_.log_file%3F and paste it here. Don't just change editors, you are bound to run in to errors like this time to time, its best to solve them otherwise before you knowit you have ran out of all your options

Comment: It was a _nicer_ question before the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling it?

[image]

Comment: I don't want to reinstall all my plug-ins :( thats like the last thing I want to do

Comment: Your plugins are likely what's causing the issue. Do a clean install and reinstall your plugins one at a time. Not to mention that StackOverflow is for programming questions, not "help me fix my IDE" questions.

Comment: Fixing an IDE is so releated to programming that I see no problem in asking for help here. Also, many people will probably look for an answer here when their IDE get broke.